# Movable Type: Change URL using regex replace

Tags: regex, types, movable

In my `<mt:EntryBody>` text I have few urls which I want to change the pointing address.

```
http://www.myblog.com/blog/content/fruit/apple.html
```

to

```
http://www.myblog.com/blog/apple/
```

In this case word "fruit" and "apple" would be the variable. I would like to use `regex_replace` modifier to change every URL in EntryBody.

How would I write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ?

```
<mt:EntryBody regex_replace="/content\/\w*\/([^\.]*)\.html/","$1/">
```

$1 will get the info from what matched inside "( )"